# Detecting radiation from tritium keychain

Tags: radiation, x-rays, gamma-rays

I am measuring radiation from 6 tritium glow keychains. Usual gamma detector does not detect anything (this is expected), but on beta detector with thin window I am getting about 5 counts per second.

Count rate drops by mere 10% when using 1mm plastic shield.

My understanding is that I am not actually detecting betas, but rather weak secondary X-Ray radiation generated when electrons travel through keychain's plastic. Is that correct?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree with the general conclusions regarding soft x-rays. I have measured the attenuation of x-rays in every day materials at energies below 20 Kev and to a first approximation can be described by :-
  E½  = K t^1/3.25  where t is the thickness in cm.  E½  the energy at which the intensity is reduction to ½ . K is the coefficient of the material.
For example a sheet of solid styrene K = 17.77 and E½ = 8.7 Kev for 1 mm thick sample. While the exact K value will depend some what on your particular specimen it might be interesting to compare the attenuation using other materials.

Cling film  13.3,  Black card 18.4,  Writing paper 23.5,  Black polythene 14.7, 
Clear polythene 13.3,  Mica 51, PCB Fibre glass 40, Beryllium 11.23 , Aluminium 46.6,

Comment: Rearranging the equation for a 1 mm solid styrene sheet for 90% transmission gives K = 31.72 and  15.6 Kev.

Comment: I don't understand this intriguing analysis. Tritium betas have average energy 5 keV, rounghly 90% below 10 keV, none above the endpoint around 17 keV. Why do you "solve" in your comment for 16 keV?

Comment: I suspect because the styrene acts as a hardening filter, but I find this analysis confusing as well.

Comment: Isn't the OP detecting bremsstrahlung? If I read his question correctly that is exactly what he's asking.

Comment: @MartinPage Mind, I've been thinking on this for a year -- there's just too much variability to create such a general "approximation"; I think you're back-calculating your way into bad data. But.. I could be misunderstanding.

Take a look at the chart for polystyrene attenuation: http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ComTab/polystyrene.html

As well as this calculator, which includes some of the materials you have "coefficients" for: http://web-docs.gsi.de/~stoe_exp/web_programs/x_ray_absorption/index.php

Let me know if their numbers match your expectations.

Comment: I don't know why this answer is rated highest.  It does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

I also have such a "betalight" and I can provide some data. I took a spectrum with our Amptek energy-dispersive x-ray detector. One can see a Bremsstrahlung spectrum consistent with the maximum beta energy of 18.6 keV. There are also the characteristic zinc K$\alpha$ and K$\beta$ peaks. I attribute those a zinc-oxide phosphor. 
[image]

Comment: I have been referring to this diagram for some time now but I am still not sure what it is we are looking at.  Is the Bremsstrahlung a direct result of tritium beta decay, XRF of a phosphor in the tube, or originating from bombarding electrons from an xray tube?  When I use my scintillator on a green tritium keychain I get a distinct peak down in the low teens keV.  I am assuming that this peak is 11 keV based on this diagram but I am not at all sure.

Comment: @cdavidyoung The beta electrons are emitted with a kinetic energy of up to 18.6 keV. Those electrons then emit the wide Bremsstrahlung spectrum in the interaction with matter (deflected by nuclei). Those electrons can also knock out electrons from the K-shell (1$s$ orbitals) from atoms. When those holes are filled one can get the characteristic x-ray lines. In this key chain, the heaviest element is the zinc of the zinc oxide phosphor, causing the lines at 8.6 keV and 9.6 keV.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation!  To add to the confusion I found an article that claims "Bremsstrahlung plays a marginal role in the field of radioactivity, since beta decay electrons do not often travel fast enough. On the contrary, it plays an important role in cosmic rays and in particle accelerators.": http://www.radioactivity.eu.com/site/pages/Bremsstrahlung.htm - I would appreciate your commenting on this.  Thanks!

Comment: @cdavidyoung Typical beta energies are 1 or 2 MeV. The beta energy of tritium is exceptionally low, so this is a case of "not often". It is the same energy as of the electron beam in the old-fashioned CRT displays and of low-energy x-ray generators. (Although, typical beta decay electrons travel "too fast", at relativistic speeds. Yes cosmic rays and accelerators have even higher energies, but I do not understand how this would be relevant.)

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion seems reasonable. The energy of the beta particles from tritium is only about 5keV and they're stopped by a cm or so of air, so a 1mm plastic sheet would certainly stop them.

My only concern is that the X-rays are going to be very soft and their intensity very low. A quick Google found [this article](http://acis.mit.edu/acis/spie96/sej_calpaper/paper.html) about using X-rays from tritium decay as a calibration source, but the flux they measure is very low. I wonder whether you are detecting radioactivity from some other source e.g. contamination of the tritium by some other radionuclide.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not detecting anything related to Tritium.  To actually detect the betas you would have to cut the keychain open and use an open gas proportional counter.  However, it is a valid method to simply use the photons generated by the keychains to calculate the amount of radioactivity.  This is called scintillation detection.

Comment: I have a Wm. B. Johnson GSM-115 geiger counter with a pancake probe and it has no problem detecting the betas directly.  Ambient is 50 cpm and my tritium keychain measures 500 cpm.  See my scintillation results in another answer.  It resulted in 9.5 cps of Bremsstrahlung photons.  I am fairly sure these photons originate from tritium because the shape and location of their measured peak is the same as the Bremsstrahlung independently measured by Pieter.

Answer (score 1):

After consultation with Pieter who has the most authoritative answer, I will throw in my scintillator results.  This image is the result of scanning a tritium keychain with a Hamamatsu R6095 PMT and a 25x10mm NaI crystal running at 800V.[image: tritium keychain with a Hamamatsu R6095 PMT and a 25x10mm NaI crystal]  Based on Pieter's Bremsstrahlung diagram I have placed the peak at 11keV.  The rest of the graph is background radiation.

So the answer is that the "usual gamma detector" will indeed detect the Bremsstrahlung that results from the tritium beta decay.  By "usual" I mean of course that you are using a high enough voltage on your scintillator so that the energies above at least 10keV are visible.

And, no, it is not caused by weak secondary X-Ray radiation generated when electrons travel through the keychain's plastic.  It is caused by Bremsstrahlung xrays as the original beta particle passes close to positively charged nuclei.  Diverting the electron from its original path causes a loss in kinetic energy that results in the emission of a photon.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that You are probably detecting X-ray radiation, but not from tritium. The inner surface of tritium keychain (also known as betalight) glass is covered with phosphor. When electrons from tritium beta decay hit the phosphor layer, they excite phosphor and force it to emit photons. I guess that is what You're actually detecting.

Comment: As you say, the phosphor emits photons (in the visible range).  What he is detecting are beta particles, apparently using a Geiger counter.  I don't know why they wouldn't be coming directly from the tritium.  As I describe in my answer, the Bremsstrahlung photons can be detected as well with a scintillator.