# Intensity of the cherenkov radiation of tritiated water

Tags: cherenkov-radiation

Assuming that I have a large quantity of tritium oxide (T2O), or 100% tritiated water, how luminous would it be due to Cherenkov radiation? What color would it be to the human eye, and how much of it would be in the UV spectrum?

As it decays, the tritiated water would decompose into gases, but we ignore this for the moment. Only the first instants when the T2O has just been

By "large quantity", I mean from 1 cc to 1 m³, though I am also curious what a swimming pool or a lake of the stuff would look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The betas from tritium have low energy, [at most 18.6 keV](http://nucleardata.nuclear.lu.se/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=10003), which is much less than the electron mass of 511 keV. So these are nowhere near relativistic. They not faster than light in water and won't cause Cherenkov light.

What one sees in tritium lights is fluorescence from for example rare-earth-doped ZnO, as in the spectrum that I used in my answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/389609/is-my-tritium-keychain-emitting-significant-amounts-of-radiation).

Comment: So they aren't nearly as fast as needed to beat the speed of light in water. Damn, looks like I'll have to find something else for my (voluntarily ridiculous) Cherenkov illumination theoretical system.